# What is the correct reaction mechanism?

Tags: carbonyl-compounds, nucleophilic-substitution, aldol-reaction

I came across this question:

> [image]

I propose two things to happen:

1. It can undergo Aldol condensation

or

2. it can undergo SN by replacing $\ce{-Cl}$ with $\ce{-OH}$.

But apparently, both these mechanism give the wrong product. I’m unable to find out what is going on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see what went wrong. Such questions are often confused with aldol or cannizarro as they have a carbonyl group and a base is given.

Actually this is a completely different name reaction called Favorskii rearrangement. The key to identify it is that its applicable to α-halo ketones.

In Favorskii rearrangement, the base takes α-hydrogen from that side of ketone which is opposite to the side having the halogen. It then forms a 3 member cyclic ring as an intermediate product. The product formed is a carboxylic acid derivative, mostly ester.

You can learn more at [organic-chemistry.org](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/favorsky-reaction.shtm) or [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favorskii_rearrangement)